# How to create a multidimensional array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I create a multidimensional array in JavaScript?
I have:

```
var m = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < m; i++){
    groupsData.name_of_bar = [];
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['a'] = data[i].a;
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['ab'] = data[i].ab;
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['de'] = data[i].de;
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['gh'] = data[i].gh;
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['xy'] = data[i].xy;
}
```

If I do:

```
groupsData.name_of_bar[0]
```

I get errors:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot set property 'a' of undefined

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create the array OUTSIDE your loop. You're creating the same empty array for every loop.

Comment: Also verify that `data` exists.

Comment: I don't know what's in your `data`, but are you sure you even need this loop at all?  Would `groupsData.name_of_bar = data;` work?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.trans4mind.com/personal_development/JavaScript/Array2D.htm). That might help.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't support multidimensional arrays per se. The closest you can come is to create an array where the values in it are also arrays.

```
// Set this **outside** the loop so you don't overwrite it each time you go around the loop
groupsData.name_of_bar = [];

for (var i = 0; i < m; i++){
    // Create a new "array" each time you go around the loop
    // Use objects, not arrays, when you have named properties (instead of ordered numeric ones)
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i] = {};

    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['a'] = data[i].a;
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['ab'] = data[i].ab;
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['de'] = data[i].de;
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['gh'] = data[i].gh;
    groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['xy'] = data[i].xy;
}
```

Comment: Yes it does, they aren't different. A multidimensional array is by definition is an **array of arrays**.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek — For comparison, look at how [C does it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Multidimensional_arrays)

Comment: Yes that is how C does it. But that's not how it's done generally, in most cases they are implemented by an Iliffe vector to emulate a multidimensional array. In which basically (in programming terms) is a multidimensional array, such that we define things by if they function in the same way. For example I can use arrays to have the functionality of a stack, it's still considered a stack. Basically computation is taken as fact in the programming world where: *If it quacks and walks like a duck, then it's a duck* is considered true.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are declaring your objects are a little off.  It looks like you are attempting to create an array of objects.

```
var groupsData = {name_of_bar: []}, 
    m = 4, 
    i = 0;
for(; i < m; i++) {
    groupsData.name_of_bar.push({
        a: data[i].a, 
        ab: data[i].ab, 
        de: data[i].de, 
        gh: data[i].gh, 
        xy = data[i].xy
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration through the loop, you are doing `groupsData.name_of_bar = [];`.  This *removes* whatever else is already in there and replaces it with a blank array.

Also, when you do `groupsData.name_of_bar[i]['a']`, you need to create `groupsData.name_of_bar[i]` first.

A way to do this is:

```
groupsData.name_of_bar = [];

var m = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < m; i++){
    groupsData.name_of_bar.push({
        a: data[i].a,
        ab: data[i].ab,
        ab: data[i].ab,
        de: data[i].de,
        gh: data[i].gh,
        xy: data[i].xy,
    });
}
```

Note that in JavaScript, arrays can *only* be numerically indexed.  If you want string indexes, you need to use an object.

Also, if there are no other values in `data[i]`, then you can simplify this even further by doing:

```
groupsData.name_of_bar = [];

var m = 4;
for (var i = 0; i < m; i++){
    groupsData.name_of_bar.push(data[i]);
}
```

Heck, why not just use `groupsData.name_of_bar = data;` and lose the loop altogether?